# Use webpack externals with angular-ui-bootstrap webpack syntax

Tags: typescript, webpack, angular-ui-bootstrap, webpack-2

we use the **externals configuration option** from webpack to prevent bundling of certain imported packages (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/) into a library.

Besides we use something like suggested on Github (https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap#webpack--jspm):

```
import accordion from 'angular-ui-bootstrap/src/accordion';
import datepicker from 'angular-ui-bootstrap/src/datepicker';

angular.module('myModule', [accordion, datepicker]);
```

But it is not possible to exclude it from the bundle with something like:

```
externals: {
   'accordion': 'angular-ui-bootstrap/scr/accordion',
},
```

We also used a RegEx. No success...
It is only working if we include it completly.

Has anyone an idea?

Best regards,
Kersten